# Usar dos metodos iguales a travez de controladores MERN

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose

tengo dos rutas en mi frontend /crea y /almacén, la cuestión es que quiero que en ambas se actualicen diferentes campos de mi Schema. Estoy usando controladores pero estoy confundido en como saber cuando usar uno u otro, tengo este tema hecho un lío vean mi código para que me entiendan mejor :)

//Aquí están los controladores

```
    const productCtrl = {};

const productosExtremos = require('../models/productos');

productCtrl.getProducts = async (req, res) => {
    const products = await productosExtremos.find();
    console.log(products)
    res.json(products);
};

productCtrl.createProduct = async (req, res) => {
    const { Descr, Pcns, Pvns, Codf } = req.body;
    console.log(Descr, Pcns, Pvns, Codf)
    const newProduct = new productosExtremos({
        Descr,
        Pcns,
        Pvns,
        Codf
    });
    await newProduct.save();
    res.json(newProduct);
};

productCtrl.getProduct = async (req, res) => {
    const product = await productosExtremos.findById(req.params.id);
    res.json(product);
}

productCtrl.deleteProduct = async (req, res) => {
    await productosExtremos.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
    res.json('Producto eliminado :(');
}

productCtrl.updateProduct = async (req, res) => { //Este controller cambia algunos campos
    const { Descr, Pcns, Pvns, Codf } = req.body;
    console.log(Descr, Pcns, Pvns, Codf)

    await productosExtremos.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
        Descr,
        Pcns,
        Pvns,
        Codf
    });
    res.json('Producto actualizado!');
}

productCtrl.updateStock = async (req, res) => { //este de aca cambia otros en otra ruta
    const { Stock } = req.body;
    console.log(Stock);

    await productosExtremos.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id), {
    Stock
    };
    res.json('Stock actualizado!')
};

module.exports = productCtrl;
```

//Aca las rutas, donde viene mi confusion deberia crear otro archivo de rutas o como se cuando utilizar un PUT u otro.

```
    const { Router } = require('express');
const router = Router();

const { getProducts, createProduct, getProduct, deleteProduct, updateProduct, updateStock } = require('../controllers/create.controller');

router.route('/')
    .get(getProducts)
    .post(createProduct);

router.route('/:id')
    .get(getProduct)
    .delete(deleteProduct)
    .put(updateProduct)
    .put(updateStock)



module.exports = router;
```

//Y bueno aqui el frontend

```
    import React, {useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Almacen() {

    const [stockAlmacen, setStockAlmacen] = useState('');
    const [stockMarket, setStockMarket] = useState('');
    const [Stock, setStock] = useState('');
    const [minimoAlmacen, setMinimoAlmacen] = useState('');
    const [maximoAlmacen, setMaximoAlmacen] = useState('');

    // const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false)
    const [codigo, setCodigo] = useState()
    const [input, setInput] = useState('')
    const [id, setId] = useState('')

    let [productos, setProductos] = useState([]);

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/data/${id}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                Stock
            })
        });
        const data = await res.json();
        console.log(data)

        await getProducts();
    }

    const getProducts = async () => {
        const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/data/`);
        const data = await res.json();

        console.log(data);
        setProductos(data)
    }

    const nuevoIngreso = async (id) => {
        const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/data/${id}`);
        const data = await res.json();
        console.log(data)

        setId(id)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getProducts();
    }, []);

    return(
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <nav className="col-12 navbar  d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center container">
                    <form className="form-inline" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <input className="form-control mr-sm-2" onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} value={input} type="search" placeholder="Ingresa un codigo o descripcion" aria-label="Search" autoFocus/>
                        <button className="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Buscar</button>
                    </form>
                </nav>
                <table className="col-12 table text-center text-white">
                    <thead className="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Código</th>
                            <th scope="col">Descripcion</th>
                            <th scope="col">Stock Almacen</th>
                            <th scope="col">Minimo Almacen</th>
                            <th scope="col">Maximo Almacen</th>
                            <th scope="col">Stock Market</th>
                            <th scope="col">Stock Total</th>
                            <th scope="col">Acciones</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {productos.map((ptd) => (
                            <tr key={ptd._id}>
                                <td>{ptd.Codf}</td>
                                <td>{ptd.Descr}</td>
                                <td>{ptd.Almacen}</td>
                                <td>{ptd.almini}</td>
                                <td>{ptd.almaxi}</td>
                                <td>{ptd.Market}</td>
                                <td>{ptd.Stock}</td>

                                <td>
                                    <div className="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
                                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={(e) => nuevoIngreso(ptd._id)}><i className="material-icons">arrow_forward</i></button>
                                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary"><i className="material-icons">arrow_back</i></button>

                                        <div className="btn-group" role="group">
                                            <button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" className="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" >
                                            <i className="material-icons">edit</i>Edicion
                                            </button>
                                            <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
                                                <button className="dropdown-item"><i className="material-icons">account_balance</i>Total</button>
                                                <button className="dropdown-item"><i className="material-icons">line_style</i>Almacen</button>
                                                <button className="dropdown-item"><i className="material-icons">call_received</i>Minimo</button>
                                                <button className="dropdown-item"><i className="material-icons">call_made</i>Maximo</button>
                                                <button className="dropdown-item"><i className="material-icons">call_missed_outgoing</i>Entrada Interna</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                        ))   
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Por favor no se que estoy haciendo mal y estoy confundido. Si alguien fuera tan amable de ayudarme se lo agradecería.

Comment: ¿Exactamente cuál es el problema? Veo que tienes un detalle con las rutas. Y es que sin importar cuál ruta consumas con `GET` o con `POST`, siempre se llamará al middleware de la ruta raíz, ya que aparece de primero en la lista de rutas. Así, si haces una solicitud tipo `GET` a una ruta: `/cualquiera`, la misma, aunque no exista, será manejada por: `router.route('/').get(getProducts) `. Intenta explicar mejor el problema para poder ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Lo que quiero lograr es usar el controlador updateStock mediante el método PUT cuando envío el res a través del fetch (o eso es lo que creo que sucede) y en mis middlewares hay dos métodos PUT cual es la forma de usar uno que no sea el primero que aparece?